# Select common elements of an array of ids Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

So i have this task to resolve in Postgresql where for a given number of classIds that the user provides i have to return him the common properties of said classes.

I have three tables to represent the model (one class has multiple properties and one property can be in many classes)

Table classes:

```
---------------------------
| Id | Name | Description |
---------------------------
```

Table Properties:

```
---------------------------
| Id | Name | Description |
---------------------------
```

And finally table ClassProperties

```
------------------------
| ClassId | PropertyId | 
------------------------
```

So the users gives me an array with classIds and i have to return him all common properties of all classes (like i said above)

As of now i'm only being able to return every property of all classes with this code:

```
select p.*
from properties as p
inner join ClassProperties as cp on cp.propertyid= p.id
where cp.classid = any ('{88d5fe8f-e19e-40b4-bc65-83ac64f825b0, a2a63bea-
aeee-4d3b-817e-cc635383c571}') ;
```

The ids as u can see are Guid, but that really does't matter. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select p.*
from properties p inner join
      ClassProperties cp
      on cp.propertyid = p.id
where cp.classid = any ('{88d5fe8f-e19e-40b4-bc65-83ac64f825b0, a2a63bea-aeee-4d3b-817e-cc635383c571}')
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2;
```

The `count(*)` should be `count(distinct classid)` if duplicates are allowed.

Note:  the value "2" is the number of elements you are checking.  You can also use `array_length('{88d5fe8f-e19e-40b4-bc65-83ac64f825b0, a2a63bea-aeee-4d3b-817e-cc635383c571}')`.

Comment: First of all thank you for the fast response.Second how do you represent arrays in sql? i actually thought that was it, by the way i think i forgot to say that this is going to be called in c# with npgsql

Comment: @w84m3 . . . I don't know what I was thinking.  Your syntax is correct.